# I've got a memory leak, would this work as a fix?

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

I think I've actually got lots of memory leaks but the one which is having the biggest impact is this:

- I create a grid of 256 divs
- I pass the grid in to a function which fades out the divs
- I then remove the grid from the DOM

Is the simplest way to fix this just to add `$cells = $grid = null;` after fadeVertical completes and add `$div = null;` in currentImageToGrid? Or is it more complicated than this? (See comments for the optimizations I am talking about.)

I've cut lots of code out of this, a complete JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GBWKh/

Thanks,

Joe

```
function demoFoStackOverflow(){
    transition(750, function(){});
}

function currentImageToGrid(xCount, yCount) 
{
    var $container = $('<div />').addClass('grid').width($imgCurrent.width()).height($imgCurrent.height()).css({ marginLeft: (($imgCurrent.parent().width() - $imgCurrent.width()) / 2) + 'px' }).click(function () {
        $imgCurrent.trigger('click');
        $(this).remove();
    });
    var sliceWidth = Math.round($imageContainer.width() / xCount);
    var sliceHeight = Math.round($imageContainer.height() / yCount);
    var xMod = 0;
    var yMod = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < yCount; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < xCount; x++) {
            var $div = $('<div/>');
            $div.css({
                height: sliceHeight + yMod,
                width: sliceWidth + xMod,
                left: x * sliceWidth + xMod,
                top: y * sliceHeight + yMod,
                backgroundImage: 'url(' + $imgCurrent.attr('src') + ')',
                backgroundPosition: (0 - x * sliceWidth + xMod) + 'px ' + (0 - y * sliceHeight + yMod) + 'px'
            });
            $container.append($div);
            // $div = null; <-- See here
        }
    }
    $imageContainer.append($container);
    return $container;
}


function transition(duration, callback) {
    // The more cells we have the better it looks but it lags in ff/ie
    var x = 16;
    var y = 16;
    var $grid = currentImageToGrid(x, y);
    $imgCurrent.hide(); 

    var transitionName;
        transitionName = _args.transitions[transitionIndex % _args.transitions.length];
    transitionIndex++;

    runTransition(transitionName, $grid, x, y, duration, function () {
        var waitForAnimationToEnd = setInterval(function () {
            // Although the set interval timer used in the trasition  has finished there may still be animations running
            if (!$grid.children().is(':animated')) {
                $grid.remove();
                callback();
                clearInterval(waitForAnimationToEnd);
            }
        }, 20);
    });
}


function runTransition(name, $grid, xCount, yCount, duration, callback) {
    if (name == 'fadeUp') { fadeUp($grid, xCount, yCount, duration, callback); }
    // Lots of others removed for brevity
}

function fadeUp($grid, xCount, yCount, duration, callback) {
    fadeVertical($grid, xCount, yCount, duration, callback, 'up');
}

function fadeVertical($grid, xCount, yCount, duration, callback, direction) {
    var y = direction == 'down' ? 0 : yCount - 1;
    var $cells = $grid.children();
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        for (var x = 0; x < xCount; x++) {
            $($cells[y * xCount + x]).fadeTo(duration / yCount, 0);
        }
        if (direction == 'down')
            y++;
        else
            y--;
        if (y == 0 || y == yCount) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            // $cells = null; <-- See here
            // $grid = null; <-- See here
            callback();
        }

    }, duration / yCount);
}
```

Comment: Also - please please note that this is unfinished code, the requirements have changed a lot and it isn't optimized etc

Comment: What makes you say you have a memory leak? Slow performance, have you run a profile or two on it with dev tools...?

Comment: I just ran a quick profile here: http://i.imgur.com/ZFErLR7.jpg and it shows pretty standard ramp up while lots of painting and math is being done, then sharp declines of the garbage collection/cleanup in Chrome's javascript engine. No growth over a minute, and actually an odd flatline after 30s.

Comment: It gradually gets slower and slower - and uses more memory. Thanks for the profile, just doing one, didn't know you could do them in Chrome.

Comment: Sure thing: hit the round 'record' button to start one in the tab shown in the picture. Pretty solid tool. What browser does it get slower in? IE <=7 are known for bad circular references between events and DOM nodes (as well as slow execution of JS code in general...)

Comment: It seems okish in Chrome. Just took a heap snapshot and will do another in a few minutes. Its Firefox that really struggles - haven't tried IE yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the WebShims library (which explains why it works fine in JSFiddle.) Removing WebShims fixes the issue and after reading the documentation  I noticed this:

> extendNative (default: true): Webshims lib will automatically extend DOM-Objects with polyfilled methods and will additionally generate a jQuery plugin with this method name. If extendNative is set to false, webshims lib won't touch any DOM-Objects and will only implement jQuery plugins. Setting this option to false, might be also good for DOM performance.

I'm pretty sure that setting this will fix it, if not then I'll just remove WebShims all together.

Thanks for the help everyone who commented.

Joe

Comment: Setting extendNative :false fixes it :)